# How do I change the JRun Session Timeout?

Tags: java, jrun

If you try to launch a JRun server and initialization takes more than 30 secs, the launch fails. Is there any way to increase this 30 second limit?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are running JRun under Windows, you can tune how long the Windows Service manager will wait.  See [How to debug Windows services](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/824344) and search that page for "30 seconds".  Immediately below that you'll see a registry key you can edit.

Basically, you'll be adding creating a new DWORD key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\ServicesPipeTimeout
```

the value of this key will be the number of milliseconds in which services should start.  This is a global setting, not just for the JRun service.